# Bouncycastle elliptic curve encryption on Android

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle

I'm trying to decrypt an X509 cert on an android device using Bouncycastle. However, I am consistently getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: algorithm identifier 1.2.840.10045.2.1 in key not recognised.
```

However, when I run the exact same code on my own computer, it works perfectly fine. Is android overriding some of the bouncycastle libraries with an outdated version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think Android has full ECC capabilities yet. The bouncycastle android uses has a lot of that taken out. I would take a look at spongycastle, however, which attempts to implement all of bouncycastle's original functionality for Android.

Here's a [link](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Elliptic-Curve-Same-BC-JAR-yields-different-capability-list-on-Desktop-Java-and-Android-Why-td3724570.html) to a bouncy castle topic talking about missing ECC in android.

Here's a [link](http://rtyley.github.com/spongycastle/) to SpongyCastle

Comment: Thanks!
The first link was very helpful, I didn't know that I had to unregister bouncycastle before using spongycastle.